# Sending an email that has specific tabs of a google sheet attached as an xlsx doc

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get an email sent to a group of people that includes two tabs of a google spreadsheet as an attached xlsx doc.

The code below currently sends an attached xlsx doc with all tabs in the google spreadsheet included. However, I only want two tabs included in the attached xlsx (the tabs are called 'A' and 'B'). Does anyone have an ideas as to how I can amend the below code to do this?

I have run the below code but I'm not sure how to only send two tabs instead of the whole spreadsheet.

```
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){

  try {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();


    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

    blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");
    
    var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    var dateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd");

    var subjectLine = "AR: " + ss.getSheetByName("Ctrl").getRange("B2").getValue() + " - " + dateToday;
    var vTo         = ss.getSheetByName("Ctrl").getRange("B4").getValue();
    var vCc         = ss.getSheetByName("Ctrl").getRange("B5").getValue();
    var vBcc        = ss.getSheetByName("Ctrl").getRange("B6").getValue();
    var vFrom       = ss.getSheetByName("Ctrl").getRange("B7").getValue();
    var docLink     = ss.getSheetByName("Ctrl").getRange("B8").getValue();

    var emailBody = "Test Email"

    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      vTo,
      subjectLine,
      emailBody, 
      {
          cc: vCc,
          bcc: vBcc,
          from: vFrom,
          attachments: [blob]
        }
    );
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```